# Spotlight Search doesn't work in iOS 9.1 iPad mini

Tags: ios, ios9.1, ipad-mini, corespotlight

I have integrated spotlight search to index app content in my app. It works for all devices and shows the indexed data. However, for iOS 9.1 iPad Mini, it doesn't show any result for my app. I checked that other apps supporting spotlight indexing also don't show spotlight search results from their app content , only on this device. I have tried online forums and suggested solutions like switching off Spotlight in settings for all apps and then restarting the device and then switching on the spotlight . But it doesn't work. Is this a known device specific issue or is there some other setting that I don't know about .

Comment: I have the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From apple documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/index.html

> NOTE
>
> Although app search is available for iOS 9 users, the search
>   functionality of NSUserActivity and Core Spotlight is not supported on
>   iPhone 4s, iPad 2, iPad (3rd generation), iPad mini, and iPod touch
>   (5th generation).

Comment: I guess they added this documentation a little later. Thanks for sharing :)